# stored procedure taking lot of time in Sybase ASE 15.5

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

We are running a stored procedure in Sybase ASE 15.5.
It is taking a long time to execute (about 1 hr), however this issue is randomly reproduced i.e some times it runs within few minutes.

Please find the output of sp_monitor captured on that spid ehen it was occuring.

```
1> sp_monitor "event","133"
2> go
 WaitTime Description                                        
 -------- -------------------------------------------------- 
   216900 waiting for incoming network data                  
    86000 waiting on run queue after yield                   
     1200 wait for i/o to finish after writing last log page 
      600 waiting for last i/o on MASS to complete
```

Comment: and the stored procedure code is..

Comment: also you have to show query plan

Comment: Did you found out the reason for this?